# How to add radio buttons in Gitlab markdown?

Tags: checkbox, gitlab, markdown

I am preparing an issue in Gitlab where I want the assignee to select one of 2 or even 3 options. I have something like:

```
- [ ] Task
  - [ ] Yes
  - [ ] No
```

That works but I want to enforce that the user can only select either Yes or No in this case. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Shame there is no solution for this 3 years later... I have the same need but was not able to find too... I found a markdown fork that has this option ==> https://github.com/brikis98/wmd.   I think it is possible to insert this in self hosted gitlab (maybe). But I cannot see any way to get this working in gitlab.com as of now.. will keep digging ;)

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that I am not the only one with this problem...

Comment: If this is something you still want, I recommend filing a feature request. I don't see an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Opened feature request to the Gitlab team [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/427299). Please add a thumbs up if you have the same need as I do.